# Hibernate subquery of String collection match

Tags: java, hibernate, scala, jpa, criteria-api

I have a `Company` entity which has a `legalName: String` property and also an `aliases: Set<String>` property (so a One-to-many)
`Company` would be the parent
each `alias` String in the `aliases` collection would be the children

I successfully made a query that returns all companies (parents) which match the parent `legalName` property with a search query string (LIKE), but I also want to return companies (parents) that have an alias (children) that matches the search query string as well (all companies that either match the legal name, or at least one of the aliases, or both)

I apologize in advance because I feel like this is a very simple case, and I'm very used to writing plain SQL and this is my first time ever playing with Hibernate or any JPA implementation

Here's my code

```
val em: EntityManager = styxDao.getEntityManager
val criteriaBuilder: CriteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder
val cq: CriteriaQuery[CompanyEntity] = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(classOf[CompanyEntity])
val companyEntityType: EntityType[CompanyEntity] = em.getMetamodel.entity(classOf[CompanyEntity])
val companyEntityRoot: Root[CompanyEntity] = cq.from(classOf[CompanyEntity])
var query: CriteriaQuery[CompanyEntity] = cq.select(companyEntityRoot)



if (countryCode == null) {
  query = query.where(
    criteriaBuilder.or(
      criteriaBuilder.like( // if legalName matches ("LIKE") the search string
        criteriaBuilder.lower(companyEntityRoot.get(companyEntityType.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("legalName", classOf[String]))),
        "%" + legalNameQuery.toLowerCase + "%"
      ).asInstanceOf[Expression[jBoolean]],
      // if any of the aliases match ("LIKE") the search string 
    )
  )
}
```

The aliases isn't an entity per-se, it's just a collection of strings, I just want to add a second criteria in my OR that returns true if any of the aliases matches the same `legalNameQuery` search string

As I mentioned earlier, if I remove the `OR` part and just run the legalName string match, it works, what doesn't work is the second part of the `OR` that would match the aliases

Comment: Probably with `any(subquery)` ? I'm just not sure how to make the subquery return whether or not any of the strings in the collections matches the query with the `a like b` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work, had to `join` the `aliases`

```
query = query.where(
    criteriaBuilder.or(
      criteriaBuilder.like( // if legalName matches ("LIKE") the search string
        criteriaBuilder.lower(companyEntityRoot.get(companyEntityType.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("legalName", classOf[String]))),
        "%" + legalNameQuery.toLowerCase + "%"
      ).asInstanceOf[Expression[jBoolean]],
      criteriaBuilder.like (
        criteriaBuilder.lower (companyEntityRoot.join("aliases") ),
        "%" + legalName.toLowerCase + "%"
      ).asInstanceOf[Expression[jBoolean]]
    )
)
```